# How to plot Pandas multilabel data scatterplots in Seaborn using facetgrid?

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot, seaborn

I have a dataset which have multiple labels. I want to create a Facetgrid of scatterplots using Pandas and Seaborn. In addition this dataset has different origin which I also want to compare. (For example, this could be the prediction of different ML algorithms and the true labeling in two plots side by side). The plot I want is something like this with room for more methods and labelings:

[image]

Here the right column is the first labeling and the left is the second.

Currently my Pandas dataframe looks like this: l1, l2, method, x, y. Where l1 and l2 are the different labelings. I can plot one column using the following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='method', hue='l1')
g.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')
sns.plt.show()
```

But how do I get the second column? The intuitive thing would be to have the hue parameter be a list but that doesn't work.

Comment: You will maybe want to read http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify your dataframe:

```
l1_df = df[['l1','method','x','y']]
l1_df['label_type'] = 'l1'
l1_df.rename(columns={'l1':'label'}, inplace=True)

l2_df = df[['l2','method','x','y']]
l2_df['label_type'] = 'l2'
l2_df.rename(columns={'l2':'label'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([l1_df,l2_df])
```

Then use the truly intuitive option, `col`, from the [docs](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html):

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='method', col='label_type', hue='label')
g.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')
sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: Works! But with the above code I am duplicating the x,y data to make the different labelings plot along the columns.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what you want? Your example plot is made up of duplicated x,y data. I thought the goal was to create the exact same plots side by side with different hues indicating the different labels of the predicted and true sets for those (x,y) coords in each method. If you want to still be able to run analysis on the raw data, you can always make the concatenated dataframe a new object via `new_df = pd.concat([l1_df, l2_df])` so that you still have `df` to work with.

Comment: Correct. However, to me it seems wrong to have to duplicate every instance for every additional label just to able to plot multi-label data. Or maybe my understanding of how to do data representation in Pandas is limited?